# Issue Reading EMV visa credit card record

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I have  developed an android app to read EMV chips, i was able to read most of the EVMs for visa, master , American Express. 
except of one visa card,its chip looks different from the others,i know EMV does not specify which files data is stored in, so what i did is reading all files and records but it always return .

SW1-SW2 6A 83 
Record not found

attachment is the picture of the Emv chip .

[EMV Chip For Visa Credit Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIUnU.png)

any idea what chip type is this ?

Comment: AFAIK you should read files as specified in *Application File Locator* from the response to the `GET PROCESSING OPTIONS`. Try to read the card with [javaemevreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader).

Comment: @vlp this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

by read i assume you refer to READ RECORD. When Application File Locator( AFL) is not available, you do not have to do READs. It is using the identifiers from ALF you are supposed to do READs.

Comment: the application locator is available , and i can get the PDOL  if i read using nfc, but when i do the same steps using usb reader it always can not proceed.
this my  PDOL ->
t 9f830C9F 66 
                 04 
           9F 02
                     06 
            5F 2A 
                      02 
             9F 37 
                      04

Comment: would be better if you update your mail thread with both set of logs